# How can I make the html file read values from a config.js file

Tags: javascript, html

I have an index.html where I make a call to some google API and I am passing the keys and client id in the html file itself.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        var CLIENT_ID = 'abc';
        var API_KEY = 'xyz';
// some code
</scipt>
```

But I want the html to read these two values from a config.js rather than passing/exposing these values in the html file.

Comment: HTML doesn't read files. What's your back end framework?

Answer (score 1):

If you make an API call from the front-end, no matter what, the credentials will be exposed in the format required for transport.

If you need the credentials to be hidden on the front-end, you need to wrap the API call in a call from the server-side that has the credentials kept out of the user's reach.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what framework you are using for your backend, there are a few options. nodeJS for example would use ldapauth package for this

Answer (score 0):

You can include ("load") js file in html by adding this to the head section:

```
<script src="config.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But! If your javascript works in the front-end, you have to expose the API_KEY anyway.

In such a place use only keys meant for this by API vendor.

For example Google has special keys for that, for which you can set extra security options using their developer dashboard.

Alternatively one can make a call from the backend server, which then presents the information through its own API. This approach is harder to implement, but more secure and adds some extra possibilities, for example API caching to spend less on API fees.